# Word for a self criticizing person?

Tags: phrase-request

What do you call a person who *criticizes his own self*? Is there a specific word for him?
take example of the following self-criticism:

> "There's no room for demons when you're self-possessed." *([Source](http://www.goodreads.com/author/quotes/90150.Carrie_Fisher))*

Comment: Would you give an example of the type of sentence where you would like to use this word? Do you want it to have a positive, neutral, or negative tone? [Details, please](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/439/)

Comment: I didn't actually have a sentence in my mind, but for example lets say this type of sentence ; "There's no room for demons when you're self-possessed." a quote by Carrie Fisher.
http://www.goodreads.com/author/show/90150.Carrie_Fisher/

Comment: That's really helpful. Would you edit that into your question please? It will help others find it if they have a similar question. Comments aren't searched.

Comment: @ColleenV done, thanks for pointing that out, didn't know it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If somebody has very low self-esteem and is a very severe critic of themselves, you can describe them as self-critical or self-reproving.

> In my experience, no species of performing artist is as self-critical as a dancer. *Susan Sontag*

If somebody mildly plays down or makes fun of their own achievements- out of a sense of modesty- you can call them, and what they say, [self-deprecating](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/self-deprecating).